# AddTarget does not work on UITextField rightView

Tags: ios, ios6, uibutton, uitextfield

I am adding following code to add a drop down button on UITextField right side

```
self.filterTextView.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downArrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(showPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.filterTextView.rightView = btn;
```

Button is visible on right sie but `showPicker` method doesn't get called when i tap on button

I am running the code in iOS 6

Comment: can u please share you whole code. I just pasted you code and it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running your code and it is working for me.

Also, you can manage that without a button, you can use `UITextFieldDelegate`.

`self.filterTextView.delegate = self`

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.filterTextView)
    {
        [self.filterTextView resignFirstResponder];
        //here open picker
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. But ui design needs uitextfield with arrow on the right side. if you tap on the button showp